# Cómo puedo hacer un bucle más eficiente?

Tags: python-3.x, bucles, optimización

estoy tratando de resolver un Kata de Codewars llamada "Sum of Pairs".
El ejercicio en sí lo he resuelto porque da el resultado requerido, pero es cierto que el tiempo que tarda en realizar ciertas pruebas es muy largo.
Quería saber cómo poder optimizar este loop para que el tiempo de ejecución se reduzca.

*(En caso de ser necesario, os dejo el enunciado del Kata: Dada una lista de números enteros y un valor, define una función que devuelva los dos pares de números que sumen dicho valor estando más a la izquierda posible.)*

```
def sum_pairs(x,condition):
    second_condition=False
    results=[]
    upper_limit=len(x)-1
    lower_limit=len(x)
    for i in range(upper_limit):
        for j in range(1,lower_limit):
            if i!=j:
                entry=[x[i],x[j]]
                if sum(entry)==condition:
                    second_condition=True
                    results.append([[x[i],x[j]],i+abs(i-j)])
                    print(results)
    if second_condition==False:
        return None
    else:
        almost_final= min(results,key=lambda x:x[1])
        return almost_final[0]
```

Comment: traduce pregunta, estas en SO en español de lo contrario terminará cerrada

Comment: ¿Puedes poner algún ejemplo por si alguien no entiende que significa **más a la izquierda posible**?

Answer (score 1):

Pues a vote pronto se me ocurre algo así:

```py
def sum_pairs(number_list, value):
    for j in range(1, len(number_list)):
        for i in range(0, j):
            if number_list[i] + number_list[j] == value:
                return [number_list[i], number_list[j]]
    return None

print(sum_pairs([11, 3, 7, 5], 10))       # [3, 7]
print(sum_pairs([4, 3, 2, 3, 4], 6))      # [4, 2]
print(sum_pairs([0, 0, -2, 3], 2))        # None
print(sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10)) # [3, 7]
```

La idea es, empezando desde el segundo elemento, ver si él con algunos de los anteriores suman el valor deseado, si no comprobar el tercero con los anteriores, si no al cuarto... y así hasta encontrar el primer resultado. Si no hay resultados devolvemos None.

Esto es, si L es la lista y los índices comienzan en 0, la recorreríamos tratando de ver si se cumple la condición tal que así:

L[0] + L[1] == valor?
L[0] + L[2] == valor?
L[1] + L[2] == valor?
L[0] + L[3] == valor?
L[1] + L[3] == valor?
L[2] + L[3] == valor?
L[0] + L[4] == valor?
L[1] + L[4] == valor?
L[2] + L[4] == valor?
L[3] + L[4] == valor?
L[0] + L[5] == valor?
...

Un saludo.